# event.path returns undefined only for Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, firefox

I have an application in vue.js and I'm trying to get some values using event.path. When I run it on chrome works perfect but when I run on firefox I get the error below

```
29  mounted () {
30
31  var teste = document.querySelector('body').onclick = (e) => {
32      e.path.forEach(o => {
33        console.log('--> ', o.className);
34      })
35    }
36 }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: e.path is undefined                     Index.js:34
    <anonymous> Index.js:32
```

There's another way to run this code on both browsers?

Comment: 'i' in your code is the event. Your title does not reflect the issue. Searching for "event.path" gives dupes - I changed to `e`, changed the title and closed as dupe